# How to resolve this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, linkedin-api

I was trying to download a full course from LinkedIn Learning using a
code from GitHub. I have already downloaded a couple of courses
before but this time, when I tried to download another course, the
error appeared.

PS: I do have a premium LinkedIn membership. Can't watch a course online all the time - that's why I download on my PC.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import sys
import re
import os
import string
import config
import logging

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

login_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/'
post_login_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'
course_api_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning-api/detailedCourses??fields=fullCourseUnlocked,releasedOn,' \
          'exerciseFileUrls,exerciseFiles&addParagraphsToTranscript=true&courseSlug=%s&q=slugs'
video_api_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning-api/detailedCourses?addParagraphsToTranscript=false&courseSlug=%s' \
            '&q=slugs&resolution=_720&videoSlug=%s'
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
}

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class Lld:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()
        self.base_path = config.BASE_DOWNLOAD_PATH if config.BASE_DOWNLOAD_PATH else 'out'

    @staticmethod
    def plain_cookies(cookies):
        plain = ''
        for k, v in cookies.iteritems():
            plain += k + '=' + v + '; '
        return plain[:-2]

    @staticmethod
    def format_string(raw_string):
        replacement_dict = {u'Ä': 'Ae', u'Ö': 'Oe', u'Ü': 'Ue', u'ä': 'ae', u'ö': 'oe', u'ü': 'ue', ':': ' -'}
        invalid_chars = r'[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+'
        u_map = {ord(key): unicode(val) for key, val in replacement_dict.items()}
        raw_string = raw_string.translate(u_map)
        raw_string = re.sub(invalid_chars, ' ', raw_string).strip().encode('utf-8')
        i = 0
        for c in raw_string:
            if c in string.ascii_letters:
                break
            i += 1
        return raw_string[i:]

    @staticmethod
    def format_time(ms):
        seconds, milliseconds = divmod(ms, 1000)
        minitues, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
        hours, minitues = divmod(minitues, 60)
        return '%d:%02d:%02d,%02d' % (hours, minitues, seconds, milliseconds)

    def download_file(self, url, path, file_name):
        resp = self.session.get(url, stream=True)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        try:
            with open(path + '/' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
        except Exception as e:
            os.remove(path + '/' + file_name)
            print(e)

    def download_sub(self, subs, path, file_name):
        with open(path + '/' + file_name, 'a') as f:
            i = 1
            for sub in subs:
                t_start = sub['transcriptStartAt']
                if i == len(subs):
                    t_end = t_start + 5000
                else:
                    t_end = subs[i]['transcriptStartAt']
                caption = sub['caption']
                f.write('%s\n' % str(i))
                f.write('%s --> %s\n' % (self.format_time(t_start), self.format_time(t_end)))
                f.write('%s\n\n' % caption)
                i += 1

    def download_desc(self, desc, course_url, path, file_name):
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        with open(path + '/' + file_name, 'a') as f:
            f.write('%s\n\n%s' % (desc, course_url))

    def get_logged_session(self):
        logging.info('Authenticating to LinkedIn')
        login_page = BeautifulSoup(self.session.get(login_url).text, 'html.parser')
        csrf = login_page.find(id='loginCsrfParam-login')['value']
        logging.info('Csfr token: %s' % csrf)
        login_data = urllib.urlencode(
            {'session_key': config.USERNAME, 'session_password': config.PASSWORD, 'isJsEnabled': 'false',
             'loginCsrfParam': csrf})
        headers['Cookie'] = self.plain_cookies(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies))
        self.session.headers.update(headers)
        resp = self.session.post(post_login_url, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            logging.error('Could not authenticate to LinkedIn')
        else:
            logging.info('Authentication successfully completed')

    def download_courses(self):
        token = self.session.cookies.get('JSESSIONID').replace('"', '')
        self.session.headers['Csrf-Token'] = token
        self.session.headers['Cookie'] = self.plain_cookies(requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies))
        self.session.headers.pop('Accept')

        for course in config.COURSES:
            resp = self.session.get(course_api_url % course)
            course_data = resp.json()['elements'][0]
            course_name = self.format_string(course_data['title'])
            logging.info('Starting download of course [%s]...' % course_name)
            course_path = '%s/%s' % (self.base_path, course_name)
            chapters_list = course_data['chapters']
            chapter_index = 1
            logging.info('Parsing course\'s chapters...')
            logging.info('%d chapters found' % len(chapters_list))
            for chapter in chapters_list:
                chapter_name = self.format_string(chapter['title'])
                logging.info('Starting download of chapter [%s]...' % chapter_name)
                chapter_path = '%s/%s - %s' % (course_path, str(chapter_index).zfill(2), chapter_name)
                if chapter_name == '':
                    chapter_path = chapter_path[:-3]
                videos_list = chapter['videos']
                video_index = 1
                logging.info('Parsing chapters\'s videos')
                logging.info('%d videos found' % len(videos_list))
                for video in videos_list:
                    video_name = self.format_string(video['title'])
                    video_slug = video['slug']
                    video_data = (self.session.get(video_api_url % (course, video_slug)))
                    try:
                        video_url = re.search('"progressiveUrl":"(.+)","streamingUrl"', video_data.text).group(1)
                    except:
                        logging.error('Can\'t download the video [%s], probably is only for premium users' % video_name)
                        continue
                    logging.info('Downloading video [%s]' % video_name)
                    self.download_file(video_url, chapter_path, '%s - %s.mp4' % (str(video_index).zfill(2), video_name))
                    video_data = video_data.json()['elements'][0]
                    if config.SUBS:
                        try:
                            subs = video_data['selectedVideo']['transcript']['lines']
                        except KeyError:
                            logging.info('No subtitles avaible')
                        else:
                            logging.info('Downloading subtitles')
                            self.download_sub(subs, chapter_path, '%s - %s.srt' % (str(video_index).zfill(2), video_name))
                    video_index += 1
                chapter_index += 1

            exercises_list = course_data['exerciseFiles']
            for exercise in exercises_list:
                try:
                    ex_name = exercise['name']
                    ex_url = exercise['url']
                except (KeyError, IndexError):
                    logging.info('Can\'t download an exercise file for course [%s]' % course_name)
                else:
                     self.download_file(ex_url, course_path, ex_name)
            description = course_data['description']
            logging.info('Downloading course description')
            self.download_desc(description, 'https://www.linkedin.com/learning/%s' % course, course_path, 'Description.txt')


def main():
    lld = Lld()
    lld.get_logged_session()
    lld.download_courses()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Error that appears**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lld.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "lld.py", line 182, in main
    lld.get_logged_session()
  File "lld.py", line 104, in get_logged_session
    csrf = login_page.find(id='loginCsrfParam-login')['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Just stop. Did you read the guidelines on [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]? There is just _so much_ code here, and at least 90% is irrelevant to the issue

Comment: As @roganjosh mentioned, you have included a substantial amount of code which is unneeded. Also the way you uploaded your traceback is almost illegible. When submitting code to StackOverflow, please narrow it to the code causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that `login_page.find(id='loginCsrfParam-login')['value']` has a null value (a value of None).

This is probably because the file you are parsing with Beautiful Soup (a very slow parser btw, but good for learning) does not contain the requested tag, or that tag does not have the 'value' attribute

**EDIT:**
The reason you are getting this error is that there is no tag with the id "loginCsrfParam-login"

Here is a Diagram of Whats going on in the interpreter:

1. Page is fetched (www.linkedin.com/index.html), this page does not contain anything with the id of "loginCsrfParam-login".
2. BeautifulSoup parses the page for a tag with the
   "loginCsrfParam-login", it doesn't find it, so it returns None.
3. You didn't try to write safe code, so you didn't check the return value of parse.
4. Python failed because you tried to refer to the member of an empty class

Comment: You are parsing the page for the wrong attributes. The HTML code for linkedin.com (login_page) does not contain anything with the id "loginCsrfParam-login"

Answer (score 0):

your login_page doesn't contain the id and therefore you are getting the error because the object whose value you are trying to find does not exist which means it is of 'NoneType'.